# Do Community Wikis affect my statistics, particularly the Accept Rate?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I've just posted a couple Community Wikis to help build lists of common RPG/DnD terms here.  Although answers to CWs should (theoretically, I believe) be contained within one community-edited answer post, that is rarely the case around here.  Often, people add separate answers (this brings up another question, I'll post separate) so that there usually ends up being three or more answers to a CW thread.

Do I still need to accept one of these answers, to maintain my Accept Rate?  Will Community Wikis still show up in my profile as having no accepted answer, and thereby eventually alert to needing one?  (Come to think, I haven't seen that alert in awhile for some that I've deliberately left open - has it been removed?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[No.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/#comment-32274)

Comment: Wow... made the character limit by a hyperlink!  Cheater!  How about the second bit, about the "consider accepting an answer" alerts?  Know anything on that?

Comment: @Iszi I *believe* that still happens for Community Wiki...

Comment: @Iszi - Most of the reminders are tied to reputation.  The more rep you get, the fewer reminders you will see.

Comment: Good information to know, Pat.  Has there already been an MSO question, or blog entry on this that you could link to?